# Given an Array A[1..n] as input,fill in a second Array B[1..n] such that B[i] = A[1] + ... + A[i]

Tags: arrays, sum, pseudocode

The running time should be O(n), this is what I came up with, is it correct? THANKS

```
for (i = 1 ; i < A[n]; i++)
  A[i] = 0

B[i] = 0;
for i in A[1..n]
  B[i] = B[i] + A[i]
```

Comment: Why not convert it to your favourite language, compile it, and see if it gives the correct result?

Comment: good idea Oli, but I'm learning for an exam and I won't be able to compile in a test, I used the first for to read in the values...but it says it should have running time O(n) in task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Your solution is the most trivial case of [*dynamic programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), a technique to greatly speed up algorithms for solutions that can be constructed from solutions from smaller sub-problems.

Your problem at hand has precisely this property: a solution to `B[n]` can be constructed in `O(1)` if you are given a solution to `B[n-1]`, and that is what your algorithm did, for a running time of `O(N)`.

Solutions like that are very helpful in practice: I once used an algorithm like yours to speed up a piece of start-up code in my program from several minutes to several seconds (it was adding vectors, so it went from `O(3)` to `O(2)`).